# Is the pushforward measure operator open?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, category-theory

For a compact Hausdorff space $X$ consider the space of signed Radon measures $\mathcal{M}(X)$.
Typically it is equipped with the topology induced by the total variation norm.
Further $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the topological dual of $\mathcal{C}(X)$ by Riesz-Markov-Kakutani.
Thus we can consider the weak$^*$ topoplogy on $\mathcal{M}(X)$.

However we look at the following topology. A subset $U$ is open iff its intersection with all balls $B_r(0) = \{ \mu \in \mathcal{M}(X)  : \lvert \mu \rvert \leq r \}$ is open in $B_r(0)$ with the weak$^*$ topology. In other words it is the filtered colimit topology of the compact Hausdorff spaces $B_r(0)$. My reference for this construction is Scholze's Analytic geometry lecture notes https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf.

Then for a given continuous surjection $f \colon X \to Y$ of compact Hausdorff spaces one can show that the induced pushforward operator $f_* \colon \mathcal{M}(X) \to \mathcal{M}(Y)$ is surjective and continuous with respect to this topology.

Now I want to show that $f_*$ is open. Is there a way to see this?